# how can i disable bottom bar of tab

Tags: android

I want to disable bottom bar of android tab. I don't want it to be disabled permanently (using sure lock). I just want it to be disabled for an app because I have buttons in my app which will take the user back and home. I tried this but no use.

```
getWindow().getDecorView()
       .setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no straightforward way to do that.
We have developed a restaurant  e-menu app which required us to hide the action-bar completely. We started with surelock but later switched to our own solution. I can not disclose it completely here but can give you some hints.

Android action-bar is provided by a system process. Terminating it will remove the action-bar. Android is actually a Linux flavor. So you can write a simple Linux program in C and send a KILL signal to action-bar process. Your program should then listen on a port and when your activity (or application) exit, it should write to that port. Your background program should then relaunch action-bar process or provide an alternative for that.

1. You will need root access
2. You need to compile for ARM

Comment: i dont want to root my device. I just want it to disable for 1 activity and enable it again when the user will proceed to next.

Comment: @Meghs I have been searching for such a solution since last 6 months. I found none. In fact its impossible by android design. Unless you find a back-door, it's impossible.